# Vega visualization in Kibana using dynamic Signal as Elasticsearch query parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I'm trying to build the Vega visualization that queries the data from Elasticsearch index, and interacts with user via Vega signals. I have a signal "handleTime" that follows user's mouse drag event. And I want to use this value as parameter to Elastic query to filter all events less then the Signal value.
Here is the example of my code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "handleTime",
      "value": 60,
      "on": [{
        "events": "[@handle:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
        "update": "invert('x', clamp(x(), 0, width))"
      }]
    },
  ],
  // Define the data source
  "data": [{
    "name": "elastic",
    "url": {
      "index": "my-index-name",
      "body": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                // ToDo: with constant '48' query works
                // "range" : { "totalTimeOnTarget": { "lte": 48 } }

                // But I want to use my signal value instead of constant, but next line of code doesn't work.
                "range" : { "totalTimeOnTarget": { "lte": { "%signal%": "handleTime" } } }
              }
            ],
        },
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  ],

 // The rest vega chart code...
}
```

Does anybody knows how I can use the signal dynamic value as query parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. [In the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/vega.html) there is a possibility to use expression function `kibanaAddFilter`. The point is that this function adds the filter to Kibana context, and then uses this filter in a query. But to use this feature, there should be removed `query` section from `URL` and add `"%context%": true` instead. Example code:

```
{
 "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
 "signals": [
  {
    "name": "deleteQuery",
    "on": [{
      "events": "mouseup",
      "update": '''kibanaRemoveAllFilters()'''
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "updateQuery",
    "on": [{
      "events": "mouseup",
      "update": '''kibanaAddFilter({"bool": {"must": [{"range" : { "totalTimeOnTarget": { "lte": invert('x', x())} }}]}}}}, 'my-index-name')'''
    }]
  },
],
// Define the data source
"data": [{
  "name": "elastic",
  "url": {
    "index": "my-index-name",
    "body": {
      "size": 10000
    }
  }
],
// The rest vega chart code...
}
```